# opencv sample code run time error using argv[]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, argv

I run this sample cod, and i get run time exception

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int _tmain(int argc, char** argv)
{
  //IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "Walk1001.jpg" ,1 );

  IplImage* img =cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
  if(!img)
     cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << endl ;



  cvNamedWindow( "Example1", 1 );
  cvShowImage( "Example1", img );

  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvReleaseImage( &img );
  cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
  return 0;
}
```

when i use `IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "Walk1001.jpg" ,1 );` instead of this  `IplImage* img =cvLoadImage( argv[1] );` program runs fine. but otherwise i got error.

What is to do with `argv`. i have came across many programs in which image is loaded through some `argv[]` syntex! how to use this array (`argv[]`) or what else?

Comment: What are you giving in argv ? Do you understand that argv is the pointer to the set of strings that are passed in command line?
In command line, you have to give a valid path of an image file.

Answer (score 1):

to use the argv array, you've got to supply arguments to your program (from the cmdline, or similar)

```
prog.exe Walk1001.jpg 19
```

now argv holds 3 elements, [ "prog.exe", "Walk1001.jpg", "19" ], and argc==3

in your program , do:

```
char * imgPath="Walk1001.jpg"; // having defaults is a good idea
if ( argc > 1 )                // CHECK if there's actual arguments !
{
    imgPath = argv[1];         // argv[0] holds the program-name
}

int number = 24;
if ( argc > 2 )                // CHECK again, if there's enough arguments
{
    number = atoi(argv[2]);    // you get the picture..
}
```

sidenote: you seem to be a beginner (nothing wrong with that!), the opencv api has changed over the years, please *don't* use `IplImage*` and cv*Functions(the 1.0 api), 
use cv::Mat and functions from cv:: namespace.

```
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char * imgPath="Walk1001.jpg"; 
    if ( argc > 1 )                
    {
        imgPath = argv[1];         
    }

    Mat img = imread( imgPath );
    if ( img.empty() )
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << endl ;
        return 1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Example1", 1 );
    imshow( "Example1", img );

    waitKey(0);

    // no, you don't have to release Mat !
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks berak. I was aware of command line argument with argv, but was confused in debug mode. thanks a lot for explaining.

Comment: I am getting run time exception. the error is line 2482 uknown function in array.cpp? i think i get this message from imshow. any cue abt that?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting run time exception. the error is line 2482 unknown function in array.cpp? I think i get this message from `imshow` after debugging.  I'm using `Mat img=imread("walk100.jpg");` but the `img.total()` returning NULL. why `imread` is returning NULL. `cvload` is working perfectly.

I got this solved, on the web i came to know about `***d.dll`. while adding dll files, I omitted the **d**, that is for release mode not for debug mode. So I just place "d", like `opencv_core244d.dll` instead of `opencv_core244.dll`

thanks all for your contribution